# How to calculate average based on more factors in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average

I have a spreadsheet and I would like to calculate average for each team for 1st half. So, for California, if it's under Home team column, then I should use Home 1st half score column, if it's in Away team column, then Away 1st half score should be used. Currently I have a formula `=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(C9:C165,C166,E9:E165),AVERAGEIF(D9:D165,C166,F9:F165))` but the problem is if a team has played only away games, then formula throws an error that it can't be divided by 0 because there are no home score results. I would like to calculate average for every team like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en):

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(C9:C165,C166,E9:E165),AVERAGEIF(D9:D165,C166,F9:F165)), AVERAGEIF(D9:D165,C166,F9:F165))`

In toher words: If you cannot make and avarage between column C and D because column C si empty - only the average of column D will be returned.

You can nest the formula into a second `IFERROR` to catch the case when column D is empty.

Comment: Should I nest it with OR for empty column D example?

Comment: The easiest thing that comes to my mind is `=iferror(iferror(AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(C9:C165,"<>",E9:E165),AVERAGEIF(D9:D165,"<>",F9:F165)),AVERAGEIF(D9:D165,"<>",F9:F165)),AVERAGEIF(C9:C165,"<>",E9:E165))`, also for sure there are also other solutions.

Comment: the above formula doesn't produce correct averages. I actually went a bit different way to combine results and use the formula from your answer